# Location significant change feature in iOS 6 is not called as often as iOS 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

My app is using the **"Location significant change"** feature.  I noticed that after compiling my app to run on iOS 6, the `location update` method is not getting invoked as often as on iOS 5.

I did some search on Stackoverflow and I noticed some advice to set the value of **CFBundleDisplayName** in plist file. However, the issue here is that the `location update` method **does** get called, only not as often as it used to. Hence, app accuracy has gone down.

Has anyone had any experience with similar issues? Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be different reasons for this

1. Significant change service uses device’s cellular radio to determine the user’s location and report changes in that location.
   If you do not have proper coverage then it would not be called
2. It gets called based on significant change in distance. So If you have not moved enough it may not be called as you might have moved more in previous testing

In case of significant change service do not expect to get very accurate data. If you want accuracy go for standard service. But there you need to compromise on battery usage.

Comment: I drive same distance which i used to drive in previous testing.

Comment: Again dear friend .. you cannot be sure if you might have lost signal on the way or there was some other problem with the network. It is based on traigulating in my knowledge. So sometimes you may get all the callbacks, sometimes you may not get depending on signal strength.